# gRPC C++ client blocking when attempting to connect channel on unreachable IP

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm trying to enhance some client C++ code using gRPC to support failover between 2 LAN connections.
I'm unsure if I found a bug in gRPC, or more likely that I'm doing something wrong.

Both the server and client machines are on the same network with dual LAN connections, I'll call LAN-A and LAN-B.
The server is listening on 0.0.0.0:5214, so accepts connections on both LANs.

I tried creating the channel on the client with both IPs, and using various load balancing options, ex:

```
string all_endpoints = "ipv4:172.24.1.12:5214,10.23.50.123:5214";

grpc::ChannelArguments args;
args.SetLoadBalancingPolicyName("pick_first");
_chan = grpc::CreateCustomChannel(all_endpoints,
                                  grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials(),
                                  args);
_stub = std::move(Service::NewStub(_chan));
```

When I startup the client and server with all LAN connections functioning, everything works perfectly.  However, if I kill one of the connections or startup the client with one of the connections down, gRPC seems to be blocking forever on that subchannel.  I would expect it to use the subchannel that is still functioning.

As an experiment, I implemented some code to only try to connect on 1 channel (the non-functioning one in this case), and then wait 5 seconds for a connection.  If the deadline is exceeded, then we create a new channel and stub.

```
if(!_chan->WaitForConnected(std::chrono::system_clock::now() +
                            std::chrono::milliseconds(5000)))
{
    lan_failover();
}
```

The stub is a unique_ptr so should be destroyed, the channel is a shared_ptr.  What I see is that I can successfully connect on my new channel but when my code returns, gRPC ends up taking over and indefinitely blocking on what appears to be trying to connect on the old channel.  I would expect gRPC would be closing/deleting this no longer used channel.  I don't see any functions available in the cpp version that I can call on the channel or globally that would for the shutdown/closure of the channel.

I'm at a loss on how to get gRPC to stop trying to connect on failed channels, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is some grpc debug output I see when I startup with the first load balancing implementation I mention, and 1 of the 2 LANs is not functioning (blocking forever):
https://pastebin.com/S5s9E4fA

Comment: I am by no means a gRPC expert, but could this be a symptom of this issue: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15889  - It looks like setting TCP_USER_TIMEOUT may be the solution to the blocking issues.

Comment: @jasonmclose Thanks for the response!  Do you know how I set that?  The details of the change don't really document how to use it...

Comment: It looks like it is set in the functions in this file: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc

Comment: So you may want to call `config_default_tcp_user_timeout` and/or `grpc_set_socket_tcp_user_timeout`.  I would try to use one of those.

Comment: I don't seem to have access to those functions as a user of gRPC.  I'm a bit confused by this change, I thought it was done to give users access to modify the timeout.

Comment: Understandable.  Again, I'm no gRPC expert.  I might suggest you contacting one of the devs in the bug ticket and asking if they would mind helping you with this particular issue.  If they give you one, come back and post it here in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to let anyone know the problem wasn't with gRCP, but the way our systems were configured with a SAN that was being written too.  A SAN was mounted through the LAN connection I was using the test failover through and the process was actually blocking because it was trying to access that SAN.  The stack trace was misleading because it showed the gRPC thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [keepaliaves](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/keepalive.md). Example usage: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/test/cpp/end2end/flaky_network_test.cc#L354-L358

Comment: I'm still experiencing the same behavior after enabling the keepalives.  I thought the keep alives would only matter once its connected.  In my example the channel cannot connect on 1 of the 2 IPs supplied to the channel.  It never gets connected to start keep alives.